# Ubuntu VM Unity GUI Not Starting After Appliance Export VirtualBox

Tags: unity, virtualbox, login

I am using VirtualBox to create an Ubuntu 16.04 VM. I had it all setup fine. It worked for a few days. It would shut down and start up just fine with no issues. I then went to copy it to another PC. I used the "File > Export Appliance" option. Afterwards, both the copy that I import and the my original VM boot to the command line login, but not to the Unity login screen. I tried starting my login manager service:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

but that does not do anything or throw any errors. I get the same issue when I clone the vdi via VirtualBox command line tools and use that to make a new VM (this test was done with a new VM I make that had the GUI working).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT 1:

Ran the following commands to get additional info.

The issue after running fsck suggested by heynnema: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0tT3_X-iMNzZ0ZxOER2ZzNBQzg/view?usp=sharing

blkid output:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0tT3_X-iMNzdk9Pdmt4bnRhVk0

contents of /etc/fstab
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0tT3_X-iMNzeVZ6eHhqcVlkTTQ

EDIT 2:

Fresh Install Partitions: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0tT3_X-iMNzS0w3eUhGSDZBR1k

Comment: Are you able to get to the GRUB menu in your VM? You may have to hold down the SHIFT or ESC key during boot to make it appear, if you don't see it automatically.

Comment: Yes I can get to GRUB

Comment: see my answer, below...

Answer (score 1):

Lets check the file system to make sure there aren't any errors.

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery Mode
- choose root access
- type `sudo fsck -f /`
- run fsck more than once if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: No errors showed up when I did this to the .ova imported VM but still no GUI and starting lightdm did not work either. Tried on my original and I got a message about something depending on swap and then I rebooted and no GUI. Tried again to see if I could get the exact message about swap and it passed everything with no message.

Comment: go back to root access and type `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and post the results as an edit to your question. You may have to take a picture with your phone... just make sure they're clear and readable.

Comment: Added edits to my post.

Comment: Did you manually add/delete/change any partitions on the VM guest? It's having trouble finding swap, but blkid and fstab look ok. It's unusual to have sda1 and sda5 on a freshly built system.

Comment: I did on a previous VM, but the one I'm working with now should have been a fresh HD. Let me try making a completely new one and doing the export function to see if I get the same problem.

Comment: I just tried setting up a completely new VM created with a brand new .vdi 16GB and it is using partition 5. See my question update for the screenshot.

Comment: Did it fail after an export?

Comment: Still installing

Comment: Seems like my fresh tests are working as expected. I am not sure what is happening to my original VM, but it may be less effort for me to transfer everything over rather than track down the issue I probably introduced. Thank you for taking the time @heynnema. I really appreciate it.